# Stored Procedure Dynamic WHERE Condition SQL

Tags: php, mysql, cursor, procedure

I'm not an expert on stored procedure, but I was wondering if I can add a dynamic where condition to a cursor. I have looked around before asking but nothing seems to fit my needs, or maybe I just can get it. 
I have two stored procedures, and one calls the other. The first stored procedure calls the second one and passes a built dynamic SQL string ("And firstname NOT LIKE blah bla...") called dynamic_sql_condition.

This is part of the second stored procedure:

```
declare resources cursor for select name from people where firstname = firstname {dynamic_sql_condition goes here} group by lastname;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using prepared statements, like this:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'select name from people where firstname = firstname {dynamic_sql_condition goes here} group by lastname';
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

You can adapt this to use with your cursor. More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: So, how does this work? PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'blah'; and then declare resources cursor for stmt1???

Comment: Since your SQL is dynamic, you can simply put it into a string, like the example above. Then use it inside your stored procedure.